# Is there any reason to not generate setters and getters for @Id fields in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, getter-setter, identifier

Assuming a JPA entity with (for example) an long id generated automatically:

```
@Entity
@AutoProperty
public class SomeItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)   
    private long Id;

    ...

}
```

Is there any reason to not generate setter and getters for this Id? One might be tempted to not generate a setter for example, since it is the responsibility of JPA to generate the ID.

Comment: Did you find out if the `Id` gets populated without any setter method (by writing a test case)?

Comment: you mean, apart from not needing to set it, or not needing to access ir?

Comment: @DataNucleus I mean from not needing to set it. Or, in other words, is it a good practice to not generate a setter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may find that you may be able to get away without putting a getter/setter on the JPA Entity from the persistence side of things.  But if you start dealing with entities that are serialized from other sources, even from your view in some cases, you will need a way to set the ID of the entity to let JPA know that it is dealing with an existing entity, if you cant set the id, then the persistence layer will just treat it as a new Object.

Answer (score 22):

I see that other comments has misguided you so I feel myself obliged to elaborate on this issue a bit, even though I can't give you a scientific and complete answer. @vcetinick wrote the current accepted answer:

> *You **may** find that you **may** be able to get away [..] from the persistence side of things.*

This quote in particular is wrong. All depends on where you put your `@Id` annotation. The [specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3_0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) says:

> *If the entity has ﬁeld-based access, the persistence provider runtime
>   accesses instance variables directly.*

Thus you are not required in any way to provide a setter or getter. Because you annotated your **field** and not a getter method (annotating the setter method will be ignored and have no bearing).

However, if you write a getter method, and annotated this method with your @Id annotation instead of your field, then we would tell our persistence provider to access our field through the accessor (*getter*) and mutator (*setter*) methods and not use reflection. In that case, **both** a getter and a setter should be present. The book [Pro JPA 2: Mastering the Java™ Persistence API](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430219564) writes on page 71 (**bold** markup by me!):

> *When property access mode is used, the same contract as for JavaBeans applies, and there must be getter and setter methods for the persistent properties. The type of property is determined by the return type of the getter method and must be the same as the type of the single parameter passed into the setter method. **Both methods must be either public or protected visibility**.*

Therefore, I usually annotate my id field, and write both a setter and getter method, but the setter method I give protected access. I just don't want any other pieces of code to have easy write access to such an important field. I don't know if this would cause problems in other domains. I'm no expert. But I don't find any rationale either as to why *not* setup an id attribute in this way. See also the [Netbeans forums](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=151387).

Answer (score 2):

`Id` is your primary key without it you will never able to insert records in the database.
In your case  `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)` it ensures that `id` will be generated for each `persist` but then also you will need a method to access it since it is primary identification of `entity` you should provide access to it .

Its like you asking some person his name and he doesn't provide it to you and you would thing he is just being rude .

Comment: That's not what the OP asked. The OP asked `Is there any reason to not generate setter and getters for this Id?`.

Comment: @AmitD So, you are not against not generating a setter in this case, correct?

Comment: I will not generate setter but definitely getter should be there. Also In case of JPA entity you always need constructor which takes Primary Key as argument.

Comment: JPA does _not_ require that an Entity has a constructor taking PK as argument (it only says it needs a no-arg constructor).

Comment: @DataNucleus Yes. It should be `should` than `need` but this additional PK constructor logically constructs Entity only when it is valid.

Comment: Actually, it depends on where you set the `@Id` annotation. EJB 3.0 [specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3_0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) says: `If the entity has ﬁeld-based access, the persistence provider runtime accesses instance variables directly.` Thus, you are **not** required to write a setter method if the annotation is set on the field.